# How to Calculate Average values in Recods of a Column Based on Status Change in Another Column in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset representing multiple 'case_id's. For each 'case_id', I need to create three new columns: 'var1_below', 'var1_at', 'var1_above'. These columns should represent the average 'session_length' for the sessions that occur after 'average_code_3' changes status, until the next change.

Here's the algorithm to calculate 'var1_at' (the process is similar for 'var1_below' and 'var1_above'):

```
For each 'case_id':
    If 'average_code_3' is "at":
        Calculate the average of 'session_length' for all subsequent sessions until 'average_code_3' changes status. The first session after the change should also be included in the average calculation.
```

For example, in the dataset below, 'var1_at' is the average of 4009, 79118, and 833151 (from the 'session_length' column), which equals 305426. 'var1_below' is NA since there is no "below" record in the 'average_code_3' column. 'var1_above' is the average of 1820655 and 886950, which equals 1353802.5. (I color code them in green and blue in the image attached, I basically want the average of those coloured records in column `session_length` )

The sample dataframe 'df' is as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(
  case_id = rep("188_161_2", 21),
  view_end_timestamp = c(1424065707, 1424112235, 1424154932, 1424155003, 1424156518, 1424156557, 1424288125, 1424288141, 1424331365, 1424413370, 1424413389, 1424413492, 1424454887, 1424496497, 1424496518, 1424496611, 1425329649, 1425329674, 1427150341, 1428037250, 1428037421),
  view_length = c(6732, 20, 42681, 55, 1515, 39, 65, 6, 43224, 7, 10, 103, 37515, 7, 21, 74, 8, 25, 45, 4, 171),
  average_code_3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "at", NA, NA, "at", NA, NA, "above", NA, NA, "above", NA, NA, "above"),
  session_num = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 10, 10),
  session_length = c(53240, 42733, 42733, 133112, 133112, 133112, 125303, 125303, 125303, 4009, 4009, 4009, 79118, 833151, 833151, 833151, 1820655, 1820655, 886950, NA, NA)
)
```

How can I implement this in R?
[image]